# How to use my index as the key when using immutability helper`update`

Tags: reactjs, immutability

I am trying to update my list using [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) suggested in react documentation, you can see the code i am currently using for the update

```
    const oldInstallment = this.findInstallmentByIndex(this.state.installmentList, index);
    let newInstallment =  {...oldInstallment}
    newInstallment.isActivated = isActivated;

    const newInstallmentList = update(this.state.installmentList, {index: {$set: newInstallment}});
    this.setState({installmentList: newInstallmentList});
```

The problem i currently have is that the `index` is not used as a value but as a key named `index` meaning instead of saying `0:{$set: newInstallment}` what the code does is `index:{$set: newInstallment}` which result in adding a new element to the array instead of updating the element in `index 0`
So my question is how can i tell this update method to use my index value as the key ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing it like this:

```
const newInstallmentList = update(this.state.installmentList, {[index]: {$set: newInstallment}});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is it! i tried {} or () or ... but i didn't consider [] !, thanks!

Comment: This is just an extra question which i hope you can help me with :), In the code i'm about  to paste the `newState` is updated properly but even after using `this.setState` in all the ways i could think of i still can't apply it to my state!, what am i doing wrong? `const newState = update(this.state, {installmentList: {$set: newInstallmentList}});
        this.setState({...newState});
        this.setState(newState);`

Comment: @AliAhmadi This could be happening if your object is deeply nested (more than 2 levels) and newInstallmentList is created as a reference instead of a new object. Also, make sure you write property name in setState call: `this.setState({ installmentList: newState });`